# jquery .load e .ajax devolvem valores diferentes, porquê?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, codificação-de-caracteres

Olá,

O meu problema é que utilizando .load ou .ajax sobre o mesmo endereço, recebo valores de dados diferentes. Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
 <span id="charset"></span><br/>
 <span id="d_nome"  title=".load"></span>
 <span id="d_nome2" title=".ajax"></span>
```

com o seguinte script:

```
$.ajaxSetup({

 beforeSend: function(dd,obj){
                 obj.dataType= "text";
                 obj.dataTypes=["text"];
                 return obj;
                },
  success: function(data){
                 console.log(".statusCode: "+data); 
                }
});

$(document).ready( function () {

$("#charset").html(document.charset);
$("#d_nome").load("/getDescricao?id=2");


$.ajax({
      url: "/getDescricao?id=2",
      success: function(data){
        $("#d_nome2").html(data);  
      }
    });
});
```

obtenho este resultado:

```
UTF-8
Farm�cias
Farmácias
```

Utilizo a formatação no ajaxSetup para garantir que os pedidos feitos são exatamente iguais. Também testei sem ajaxSetup.
O resultado deveria de ser igual uma vez que o pedido e resposta são iguais mas de alguma forma o JQuery muda a formatação da palavra 'Farmácia' quando faz o .load mas quando é feito pelo .ajax a palavra vem correta.

Obrigado pela ajuda.